# Android how can i draw single line on HelloChart

Tags: android

in my application i'm using `HelloChart`, my problem is draw single line which is RED color in below screen shot

[image]

this below code is my trying to draw that:

```
private void generateLineChart1Data() {
    lines = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; ++i) {

        List<PointValue> values = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfPoints; ++j) {
            values.add(new PointValue(j, 100f));
        }

        Line line = new Line(values);
        line.setColor(ChartUtils.COLORS[i]);
        line.setShape(shape);
        line.setCubic(isCubic);
        line.setFilled(isFilled);
        line.setHasLabels(hasLabels);
        line.setHasLabelsOnlyForSelected(hasLabelForSelected);
        line.setHasLines(hasLines);
        line.setHasPoints(hasPoints);

        if (pointsHaveDifferentColor) {
            line.setPointColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        lines.add(line);
    }

    data = new LineChartData(lines);
    data.setBaseValue(Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
    lineChartView1.setLineChartData(data);
}
```

problem is this line of code:

```
values.add(new PointValue(j, 100f));
```

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: @suraj chart with empty lines and data

Comment: @suraj `100f` must be random